# Static Variable doesnt increment in Php

Tags: php, jquery, static-variables

I have one php function on a `seperate php file` and I am calling this function `from another php file` by using an `jquery ajax call`. The php function is just increment its static value by 1 but its not incremented as I see the output. The static variable doesnt behave as I think.

Whats the reason for that ?

*Thanks in advance,*

**Simple function:**

```
function IncrementByOne()
{
    static $count = 0;

    $count++;

    echo $count;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static function variables are persistent across function calls *of the same request*. They don't keep their value across multiple requests.

Actually, that is true of all PHP variables, apart from the magic `$_SESSION` variable: They are always reset after the current request ends.

If you want a variable to persist between multiple requests, you can put it into:

- a session
- a database
- a flatfile
- APC
- memcached
- ...